# Subsetting the data frame and applying cumulative operation on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like below.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'unit': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GEH','IJK','DEF','XRF','BRQ'], 'A': [1,1,1,0,0,0,1], 'B': [1,1,1,1,1,1,0],'C': [1,1,1,0,0,0,1],'row_num': [7,6,5,4,3,2,1]})
```

[image]

I am trying to get the logic

- Step 1-Consider a subset with row_number <=4.
- Step 2- Column A,B,C has total 12 values(0's and 1's).
- Steps 3-Count number of '1' within columns A,B,C. From the example
  there are five 1's and seven 0's which    calculates to 40%(5/12) of
  1's.
- Steps-4 since count of 1's is greater than 40% create a column flag
  with 1 else if count of 1 is less than 10% then 0.

[image]

Comment: can you give feedback on the current answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I got it this time:

```
subdf = df.iloc[3:, 1:4]
df['flag'] = 1 if subdf.values.sum()/subdf.size >= 0.1 else 0
```

output:

```
  unit  A  B  C  row_num  flag
0  ABC  1  1  1        7     1
1  DEF  1  1  1        6     1
2  GEH  1  1  1        5     1
3  IJK  0  1  0        4     1
4  DEF  0  1  0        3     1
5  XRF  0  1  0        2     1
6  BRQ  1  0  1        1     1
```

Comment: Note, question was for `row_num <= 4`, not `index > 3`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. When i tried on a data set when there is only single one I was expecting flag to be '0' as its below 1/12 which is below 10%.

Comment: @dm2 II thought this was a typo. I read the question once more and I'm wondering if I understood all the logic. I'll see if OP provides more details

Comment: df=pd.DataFrame({'unit': ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GEH','IJK','DEF','XRF','BRQ'], 'A': [1,1,1,0,0,0,0], 'B': [1,1,1,1,0,0,0],'C': [1,1,1,0,0,0,0],'row_num': [7,6,5,4,3,2,1]})

Comment: @HKE then I'm not sure I understood your logic

Comment: I am sorry I will try to simplify the question

Comment: @mozway I updated the question, let me know if this helps

Comment: @HKE OK, more clear now, I updated the answer